# Conditional formatting results not a expected

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have two dates in the spreadsheet and need rows to be highlighted based on specific rules. Noticing that some rows are getting highlighted even when conditions are not met and vice versa. Please screenshot below. I have a column "Highlighting not as expected" which identifies the two case: a) no highlighting when condition is met b) highlighting when condition is not met.

[image]

Any pointer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `7/6/2022` is larger than nothing, so that highlighting makes sense. As for your first "highlighting not as expected", double check that both values are actual dates (not text that looks like a date) and that conditional formatting is set for those two cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was rectified by excluding rows where column B was blank.
= AND($B2<>"", $A2>=$B2)